# Why is my addon folder is missing from my .minecraft folder and how do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-addons

My Windows 10 computer, in the `.minecraft` folder, doesn't have an addons folder. I tried just creating one, but it doesn't seem to work. What is my issue?

Comment: What is that folder supposed to achieve, and how?

Comment: For some reason there's a double `y` in the title but when I go to edit it doesn't appear? If someone can fix it that'd be great

Answer (score 3):

On Minecraft Java editon, there are not addons.  Instead there are mods, which change the source code of the game to add cool features.  I suggest the guide found [here](https://minecrafthopper.net/help/installing-forge/) to learn how to install them.